# jQuery Ajax - Not working inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to sort this problem for 2 days. But things don't seem to be working for me.

The code I have attached is working fine outside the loop but when I use it inside the loop, it simply doesn't works the way I want and logs a empty array into the console.

On a side not, using "async: false" inside my ajax request makes the code work correctly and outputs the array completely fine in the console but as you know using "async: false" is deprecated and completely freezes UI until the request is not completed.

Any other solutions rather than setting async to false?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= splittedURLSLength; i++) {
            var extracted = extractUsername(splittedURLS[i]);
            postData = {'name' : extracted};
            ajaxRequest = $.when( $.ajax({
            url: "/check",
            type: "POST",
            data: postData
            })).then(function(returnedResponse) {
                if (returnedResponse == "1") {
                    resultsArray.push(extracted);
                }   
            });
}
console.log(resultsArray);
```

Comment: The first "a" in "ajax" stands for "**asynchronous**". Your array is probably being filled in (assuming you're not getting any server errors), but the `console.log()` call will happen long before the HTTP requests complete.

Comment: the asynchronous call continues in the background, while your script proceeds without waiting for the results. (this is simplified, but should be true enough for your problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another idea to solve it...

```
var resultsArray[]//Global or should be pass to the function...

myIterate(0);

function myIterate(idx){
    var i = idx;
    if (i < splittedURLS.length){
        var extracted = extractUsername(splittedURLS[i]);
        postData = {'name' : extracted};
        ajaxRequest = $.when( $.ajax({
        url: "/check",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData
        })).then(function(returnedResponse) {
            if (returnedResponse == "1") {
                resultsArray.push(extracted);
                myiterate(i++);
            }   
        });
    }
}
console.log(resultsArray);
```

Comment: So I wrapped the loop body in a function. And bingo! It worked like a charm. Thank you so much for the response. BTW, can you please tell me what's the logic behind wrapping the body in function? Why does it not work without wrapping it in a function?

Comment: Actually I didn't just wrapped it... I call it recursively... I like how "MPJ" explain it here: [Recursion - Part 7 of Functional Programming in JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7-N8R0-KY4).
Also: [Recursion (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

It, simply allows the ajax to execute itself before it goes to the next URL in your array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because you are logging `resultsArray` into console before it gets filled with the values from the AJAX request. The following code will give you a brief idea on how to use the data from the response-

```
for (var i = 0; i <= splittedURLSLength; i++) {
        var extracted = extractUsername(splittedURLS[i]);
        postData = {'name' : extracted};
        ajaxRequest = $.when( $.ajax({
                          url: "/check",
                          type: "POST",
                          data: postData
                      })).then(function(returnedResponse) {
                          if (returnedResponse == "1") {
                              resultsArray.push(extracted);
                              showResults(resultsArray);
                          }   
                      });
}

function showResults(resultsArray) {
    console.log(resultsArray);
    //Process your resultsArray as per requirement.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because AJAX requests are asynchronous, your console.log will fire before the first AJAX request comes back. This is how the event loop works in Javascript.

You need to move your logic into your success handler:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= splittedURLSLength; i++) {
        var extracted = extractUsername(splittedURLS[i]);
        postData = {'name' : extracted};
        ajaxRequest = $.when( $.ajax({
        url: "/check",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData
        })).then(function(returnedResponse) {
            if (returnedResponse == "1") {
                resultsArray.push(extracted);
            }
            if(i === splittedURLSLength){
               console.log(resultsArray);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. BTW "resultsArray" has negligible chance to become equal to the splittedURLSLength because returnedResponse can be 0 or 1.

Comment: Good catch. Edited my post to reflect that.